# Tomcat 7 Websocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404

Tags: javascript, java, tomcat, websocket

I am following [this](https://blog.idrsolutions.com/2013/12/websockets-an-introduction/) tutorial to establish a WebSocket connection between java server and javascript client but I am facing below-mentioned error on the browser end

**WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8080/ws/echo' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 404**

I am using tomcat 7.0.42 for Liferay and javax.websocket 1.1 jar

What I have tried :

- changing scope of javax.websocket jar to provided - same error
- using tomcat7.websocket - this cause my server to break down completely

PS: Some have suggested using tomcat 7.0.47 or above but I cant change the server for existing application this has to be done on tomcat 7.0.42

Comment: A 404 is a "Not Found" HTTP server code.  It means the URL you hit caused the server to believe that the resource you requested was not where you told it to look.  I would suggest looking into the URL you are using.  Perhaps you typo'ed it or maybe the tutorial has it typo'ed?

Comment: @CodeChimp I have checked it multiple times (different possible URL's) and also followed other tutorials but with all of them, the problem is same.
In the url "/ws" represents the package name and "/echo" represents the endpoint

Comment: Are you sure the ports are correct?  Are you sure the `EchoServer` class is being loaded?  Maybe try to put in a default constructor with a printout and see if it's being loaded at all?  Again, the server will only 404 if it can't find the resource.  Also, your URL doesn't match what I see in the tutorial, which is using `ws://localhost:8080/EchoChamber/echo` in the comments of the EchoServer.  With most app servers, the first part is the deployment name (the JAR/WAR name), so in your example your JAR/WAR would be something like `ws.jar` or `ws.war`.

Comment: the EchoChameber in tutorial is  the name of the package containing the class EchoServer with the endpoint "/echo", I named my package "ws" the rest is same, also tried the war file name in combination with package name/url

Comment: You need the `/ws/` only if you define in your endpoint path or it's in your context root. It is not related to your package. The URL should be `ws://localhost:8080/{context root if any}/echo`. If your context root is empty (ie your "welcome page" is `http://localhost:8080/`), then `ws://localhost:8080/echo` is enough. If your context root is `EchoChamber`, your welcome page is `http://localhost:8080/EchoChamber/` then your websocket URI is `ws://localhost:8080/EchoChamber/echo`

Comment: @Al1 I have also tried this but the result is same as I mentioned in my question that I am using tomcat 7.0.42 and the javax websocket support was enabled from 7.0.47 and above.I want this to be done in 7.0.42

Comment: Then you cannot use JSR356 implementation. Maybe you can give a try on [Catalina implementation](http://www.tomcatexpert.com/blog/2012/05/01/how-apache-tomcat-implemented-websocket). FWIW, here is [a sample](https://gist.github.com/chitan/3063774) I found. However, as you assume, this is deprecated in Tomcat 7.0.47+

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my understanding websocket is not supported on tomcat 7.0.42